# How to use Android Profiler and Logcat in AndroidStudio 3 in Flutter projects

Tags: android-studio, flutter, logcat, android-profiler

[image]

Running emulators with API 28 or 27 via Android Studio, the ***Flutter*** configuration successfully launches the application and there are no other problems, i.e. all other features work fine.

[image]

Why is the device not being detected by the Android Profiler? There are no resources describing similar problems.

A similar issue also occurs when trying to view *Logcat*:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make these two tools work, the *`android` module* needs to be opened. You can do this by either opening the Flutter context menu of the `android` directory in the project view or by navigating to `Tools -> Flutter`:

[image]

After this, i.e. while the *Android module* is **openend** in Android Studio, the Android Profiler and Logcat will work fine.

See also: https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/android-studio#editing-android-code-in-android-studio-with-full-ide-support

Comment: You might be right. I searched Android Studio Profile and found https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler?gclid=Cj0KCQiA14TjBRD_ARIsAOCmO9bok7ernAEs_wKpRUKDW5khCnyAwHG80sncstqkA5wJQaXW5R_4u3IaAoblEALw_wcB where Java heap and memory allocations are mentioned and I assumed this is native only. I guess you need to open AS like explained in https://flutter.io/docs/development/tools/android-studio#editing-android-code-in-android-studio-with-full-ide-support

Comment: I think there is an open issue about to make this work better in https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Flutter context menu greyed out. Tools -> Flutter menu doesn't have the option.